# boost asio - session thread does not end

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I use boost asio to handle a session per thread like this:

```
Server::Server(ba::io_service& ioService, int port): ioService_(ioService), port_(port)
{
    ba::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor(ioService_, ba::ip::tcp::endpoint(ba::ip::tcp::v4(), port_));
    for (;;)
    {
        socket_ptr sock(new ba::ip::tcp::socket(ioService_));
        acceptor.accept(*sock);
        boost::thread thread(boost::bind(&Server::Session, this, sock));
    }
}

void Server::Session(socket_ptr sock)
{
    const int max_length = 1024;
    try
    {
        char buffer[256] = "";
        // HandleRequest() function performs async operations
        if (HandleHandshake(sock, buffer))
          HandleRequest(sock, buffer);

        ioService_.run(); 
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
      std::cerr << "Exception in thread: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Session thread ended \r\n"; // THIS LINE IS NEVER REACHED
}
```

In Server::Session() I do at some point async io using async_read_some() and async_write() functions.
All works well and in order for this to work I have to have a call to ioService_.run() inside my spawn thread otherwise Server::Session() function exits and it does not process the required io work.

The problem is that  ioService_.run() called from my thread will lead for the thread not to exit at all because in the meantime other requests come to my listening server socket.

What I end up with is threads starting and processing for now sessions but never releasing resources (ending). Is it possible to use only one boost::asio::io_service when using this approach ?

Comment: This is avery strange way to use boost::asio. Have you read the tutorials? Have a look at the HTTP Server 3 example. It uses a thread pool to service multiple connections, each thread calls `io_service::run()`.

Comment: @mark I was actually looking for a solution that is simple, just a proof of concept for my program. I managed to do it eventually without using threads at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `run_one()` or `poll_one()` this will allow you to have the thread either execute a ready handler (poll) or wait for a handler (run). By only handling one, you can pick how many to execute before exiting your thread. As opposed to `run()` which executes all the handlers until the `io_service` is stopped. Where as `poll()` would stop after it handled all the ones that are currently ready.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I had some trials using the functions you mentioned but in my case it was kind of hard to know how long I would need to call run_one() because in the meantime other connections requests were coming to my server (that dispatched other threads) and they all were handled by same io_service. Simplified things for my proof of concept program not to use threads.

Answer (score 0):

The way I structured handling connection here was bad.
There is quite a good video presentation about how to design your asio server bellow(made by asio creator)
[Thinking Asynchronously: Designing Applications with Boost Asio](http://blip.tv/boostcon/thinking-asynchronously-designing-applications-with-boost-asio-5250947)